# Meaning of "I was bound Apprentice"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> My father had a small Estate in Nottinghamshire; I was the Third
>   of five Sons. He sent me to Emanuel-College in Cambridge,* at
>   Fourteen* Years old, where I resided three Years, and applied my self
>   close to my Studies: But the Charge of maintaining me (although I
>   had a very scanty Allowance) being too great for a narrow Fortune; **I
>   was bound Apprentice to Mr James Bates**, an eminent Surgeon in
>   London,

Dose here "bound" is an adjective? and does the phrase mean: Because I did n't have enough money to continue my studies I had to work as an apprentice to Mr James Bates?

Source: Gulliver Travels

Comment: It is G**u**lliver, not G**a**lliver.

Answer (score 1):

"Bound Apprentice" is a legal term of art for an [indentured servant.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apprentice) What this passage is saying is Gulliver's father could not afford to keep him in college, so Gulliver [signed a contract (or perhaps his father did) to work for a surgeon in exchange for room, board and job training.](https://work.chron.com/mean-bound-apprenticeship-21100.html)

Comment: @JamesK, I followed the spelling of Gulliver from OP's citation.

Comment: I've commented also on the OP's misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

'bound' is not an adjective here; it is a past participle. A legal agreement 'binds' the parties'. If you are subject to such an agreement then you are 'bound'. The 'term of art', as @RonJensen identifies it, is that one is 'bound apprentice' rather than 'bound as an apprentice'.